# Docker - nginx with custom conf

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

When running `docker-compose up` with the following `docker-compose.yml` file, `nginx` immediately exits after starting. When I remove the following line:

`- ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d`

`nginx` does not immediately exit.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ../wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
  php:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

How can I get `nginx` to run with a custom `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`?

Comment: Change container command to `nginx -t` and output will contain errors that were encountered by nginx during configuration analysis. In fact, something should be already present in stdout.

Comment: Yes, I see now that `"/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:34`

Comment: Looks like that snippet is just placed somewhere else in that distro. You can inspect filesystem by running `docker run --rm -ti nginx sh` and then use cat and/or ls to find out what is present inside.

Comment: That is because you override the full nginx config folder, try to mount only the default.conf file, otherwise you loose other config files required for nginx to run properly => `- ./nginx/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Comment: Thanks both of you.  It's solved.  Now, to find out why I'm getting `file not found` instead of `php`'s output.